# PHP 5 - Variable scope across include files with no classes or functions

Tags: php, variables, scope

I've read through many, many threads on this and still can't wrap my head around it.

Here's my basic issue:

`header.php` includes a file called `navigation.php`. Within `navigation.php`, `$previous` and `$next` are defined. Using echo statements I have verified they have values.

Next, `header.php` includes a file called `backnext.php`. I need `backnext.php` to know the values of `$previous` and `$next`. If I declare them as `global` at the top of `backnext.php`, I don't get errors, but `echo` statements show they are empty. If I don't, I get an `undefined variable` error.

Where exactly do I need to declare them as `global` to have `backnext.php` be able to read their values correctly?

None of these files are using functions or classes.

Comment: is navigation.php definitely included before backnext?

Comment: can u show in a code block exactly the oder it was put in (in header.php) i know you explained it but its easier to visualize that way

Comment: @Fosco - yes.

@Neal - I was trying to avoid posting over 300 lines of code, but I agree with you and can give it a go on the condensed version:
`code`
header.php:
…
include '../../includes/navigation.php';

//1st echo previous
echo $previous;
…
echo '<div id="backnext">';
// include '../../includes/leftnavbar/backnext.php'; 
echo '</div>';

//2nd echo previous
echo $previous
…

navigation.php
…
$previous = $m["$p"];
…

backnext.php
…
// 3rd echo previous
echo "previous is $previous";
…
`code`
1st says index.php, 2nd says index.php, 3rd says previous is , no value.

Answer (score 9):

If none of these files have functions or classes then `$prev` and `$next` are in the global scope and should be seen by all your include files and you shouldn't need to use the `global` keyword.

It sounds like the order of your includes may be a bit wrong.

**Update:**

If I understand correctly you have something like this:

`header.php:`

```
<?php
echo "In header.php\n";

require_once("navigation.php");
require_once("backnext.php");

echo "Also seen in header.php:\n";
echo "prev=$prev\n";
echo "next=$next\n";
?>
```

`navigation.php:`

```
<?php
echo "In navigation.php\n";
$prev = "Hello World#1";
$next = "Hello World#2";
echo "Exiting navigation.php\n";
?>
```

`backnext.php:`

```
<?php
echo "In backnext.php\n";
echo "prev=$prev\n";
echo "next=$next\n";
echo "Exiting backnext.php\n";
?>
```

If I run this I get:

```
In header.php
In navigation.php
Exiting navigation.php
In backnext.php
prev=Hello World#1
next=Hello World#2
Exiting backnext.php
Also seen in header.ph
prev=Hello World#1
next=Hello World#2
```

`backnext.php` is able to see both `$prev` and `$next`.

Comment: @watcher - I can echo $previous and $next directly before and directly after my include of backnext.php, so no, they're not getting wiped out. The only time I can't echo them is from within that file.

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably have a logic error somewhere where the contents of the variables are getting wiped, or like @Kev pointed out the flow of execution is wrong.  Here is some test code:

File: test.php

```
<?php
    $test = "Hi!";
    require_once 'test2.php';
    require_once 'test3.php';
?>
```

File: test2.php

```
<?php
    echo("Test 2: " . $test . "<br/>");
?>
```

File: test3.php

```
<?php
    echo("Test 3: " . $test . "<br/>");
?>
```

This produces the output:

```
Test 2: Hi!
Test 3: Hi!
```

Which proves that the variable `$test` is globally scoped, and should be available to any script after it is defined.

PS- Don't rely on users of SO to provide your reference material.  Go straight to the source: [Variable Scope - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)  First paragraph on that page reads:

> The scope of a variable is the context
>   within which it is defined. For the
>   most part all PHP variables only have
>   a single scope. This single scope
>   spans included and required files as
>   well.

**Edit**

Try this in `header.php` and see what happens:

```
<?php
    include 'navigation.php';
    echo($previous . " ; " . $next . "<br/>");
    include 'backnext.php';
    echo($previous . " ; " . $next . "<br/>");
?>
```

If you don't get the same output both times, then there's a problem in `backnext.php` where the variables are getting wiped.  If it does produce the same output, then move the echoes inside `backnext.php` at the very top and very bottom.  Logically its not *actually* moving them, but you can keep moving them closer and closer together until you find where the issue is.

Comment: @Kev - I agree. They should. However, the order is as I've outlined above.

Comment: Okay, I've got it... but I don't understand it. When I posted the code above I changed the path to backnext.php from absolute using BASE_URL to relative as it is there, and now it works. As it was definitely including the file, I'm confused as to why absolute/relative pathing caused this problem?